# Order five positive integers in indices form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Order from lowest to highest, $$3^{3^4},3^{4^3},3^{4^4},4^{3^3},4^{3^4}$$ $$a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}$$

So, I did the obvious, and I got $$3^{256}>3^{81}>3^{64}$$

$$4^{81}>4^{27}$$

$$3^{81}<4^{81}$$

What do I do from here?

P.S. No calculators to be used. It is a test question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Now let us check for $4^{81}=2^{162},3^{256}$

$3^2>2^3\implies3^{256}=(3^2)^{128}>(2^3)^{128}=2^{384}>2^{324}=4^{162}$

Similarly check for $4^{27},3^{81}$

As $(27,81)=27$ and $3^3>4,(3^3)^{27}>4^{27}$

and $3^{64}>2^{54}=4^{27}$